# how to change button image by javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I have 2 button and i want to change background image of that button which is clicked.

```
<input style="float:right; padding-right:10px;" name="comp_sephora" id="comp_sephora" type="submit" value="Sephora" onClick="change(this.style);">

<input style="float:right;" type="submit" name="comp_bloom" id="comp_bloom" value="Bloom" onClick="change(this.style);">
```

i have used javascript function for that:

```
function change(style)
{
    //alert(val);
    style.backgroundImage = "url(<?php echo  IMAGES."btn1.bmp"; ?>)";
    //style.color = "#000000";
}
```

but when i was clicked then image changed for only few seconds. i want to maintain that image after page reload.

Answer (score 2):

You need to return false to prevent the page from being "submitted".

```
function change(style)
{
    //alert(val);
    style.backgroundImage = "url(<?php echo  IMAGES."btn1.bmp"; ?>)";
    return false;
}
```

And then change the onclick to this *onClick="return change(this.style);"*

Answer (score 0):

Changing your type from "submit" to "button" should do the trick.

Hope this helps,